# Table refresh after AJAX POST

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, spring, spring-mvc

Basically after I have done updating and submitting information, I would like my table which is located above the form to actual change with the updated information upon submission of the form. I am using spring the spring framework alongside rest. I would like the know how I would do this. My code is still in the spike phase.
This is my ajax code for getting and updating user information:

```
$('.ajax_test').click(function() {
                    var userId = +$(this).val();
                    $.get('${pageContext.request.contextPath}/ajax/' + userId, function(user) {
                        $(".personDetails #id").val(user.id);
                        $(".personDetails #name").val(user.name);
                        $(".personDetails #username").val(user.username);
                        $(".personDetails #email").val(user.email);
                        $(".personDetails #authority").val(user.authority);
                    });
                });

        $("#myForm").submit(function(e) {
                    $.post('${pageContext.request.contextPath}/updateUser', $(this).serialize(), function(response) {
                                alert("User has been updated");
                    });

                    e.preventDefault();
                });
```

And this is my controller which handles the requests:

```
@RequestMapping("/ajax/{id}")
public @ResponseBody User getUser(Model model, @PathVariable int id) {
    User user = usersService.getUser(id);
    model.addAttribute("user", user);
    return user;
}


@RequestMapping(value = "/updateUser", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody String updateUser(User user, Model model) {
    usersService.updateUser(user);
    return "users"; 
}
```

This is my method that lists all the users:

```
@Secured("ROLE_ADMIN")
@RequestMapping("/users")
public String getUsers(Model model) {

    List<User> users = usersService.getUsers();

    model.addAttribute("users", users);

    return "users";

}
```

Does my ajax have to interact with the method above with a simple ajax GET request?